# Python 3.7 & 3.8 and VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, installation, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner at coding and I wanted to start with Python.

I am currently following a free tutorial to install Python 3.7 along with Visual Studio Code.

1. I have installed VS Code.
2. I have installed both Python 3.7 and 3.8 (the latest version available)
3. I've installed the Python and Code Runner extensions.;
4. I am 100% sure that I have added both of them to PATH.

Right now I am trying to run a simple command which is "print("Hello there")", for some reason it says on the output section:

[Running] python -u "c:\Users---\Desktop\whatever.py"

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.155 seconds

Any recommendation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Exit 0 means the successful execution of the program and a non zero exit code indicates an error. And it looks like the 'Code Runner' extension caused it. You can try to disable it in order to use the 'Python' extension.

Comment: Thank you, looks like there was sth wrong about Code Runner as you said. I changed the extension settings to "Save everything before Run" and everything works perfectly now. :)